# v-for loop error when updating data - DOMException- Failed to execute 'insertBefore'

Tags: javascript, vue.js, menuitem, v-for

I write a navigation component based on vue and ant-design-vue. the `LectureNavigation.vue` file is like this:

```html
<template>
    <div id="navigation-button">
        <a-button type="primary" style="width: 62px;
                 height: 40px;" @click="toggleCollapsed">
            <MenuUnfoldOutlined v-if="collapsed" />
            <MenuFoldOutlined v-else />
        </a-button>
    </div>
    <div id="expand">
        <a-layout-sider width="220px" style="background: #fff">
            <a-menu mode="inline" theme="dark" :inline-collapsed="collapsed" v-model:openKeys="openKeys">
                <a-menu-item v-for="(item, index) in get_lecture_index()" :key="item[0]">
                    <template #icon>
                        <MailOutlined />
                    </template>
                    <router-link :to="'/lecture/' + item[1]">{{index}} -{{ item[2] }}</router-link>
                </a-menu-item>

            </a-menu>
        </a-layout-sider>
    </div>

</template>

<script>
import { stat_instance } from "@/utils/request";
import router from "@/router/index";
import { defineComponent, reactive, toRefs, watch, onMounted } from "vue";
import {
    MenuFoldOutlined,
    MenuUnfoldOutlined,
    // PieChartOutlined,
    MailOutlined,
    // DesktopOutlined,
    // InboxOutlined,
    // AppstoreOutlined,
} from "@ant-design/icons-vue";


export default defineComponent({

    data() {
        return {
            $router: router,
            lecture_index: [
                ["0", "lks", "中华小当家"],
                ["1", "lks", "中华小当家"],
                ["2", "fefe", "美美睡一觉"]],
        };
    },

    methods: {
        get_lecture_index() {
            return this.lecture_index;
        }
    },

    created() {
        stat_instance({
            url: "/stat_api/get_lecture_index",
        })
            .then((response) => {
                this.lecture_index = response.data.detail);
                console.log("lecture_index: ", response);
                console.log("lecture_index: ", this.lecture_index);
            })
            .catch(() => {
                console.log("### Failed to request navigation file.");
            });
    },

    components: {
        // PieChartOutlined,
        MailOutlined,
        MenuUnfoldOutlined,
        MenuFoldOutlined,
        // DesktopOutlined,
        // InboxOutlined,
        // AppstoreOutlined,
    },
});
</script>

<style lang="less">

#navigation-button {
    z-index: 20;
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    top: 10px;
    left: 9px;
}

#expand {
    z-index: 9;
    position: static;
    width: 200;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    #expand {
        position: fixed;
        display: none;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 801px) {
    #navigation-button {
        display: none;
    }
}
</style>
```

but the webpage could only render the `lecture_index` in `data` method, which contains only 3 items just as the code above. It can not render the response data by a http request in the `created` method, which contains 8 items in the Array.

And when executing, the chrome reported an error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node': The node before which the new node is to be inserted is not a child of this node.
```

the whole project is as [Jionlp_online](https://github.com/dongrixinyu/JioNLP_online), when you deploy this project, type the `http://ip:port/lecture/entropy_theory_basics` could see this error page.

**So, How to successfully render the data by the http requests more than 3?**

[image: the error when rendering]

[image: the rendered page]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two root elements in you  tag, wrap it in a seperate div tag so there is only one root element.

Try this:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div id="navigation-button">
            ...
        </div>
        <div id="expand">
            ...
        </div>
    <div>
</template>
```

Comment: thanks a lot！！But I still had a question. when I load the url `http://ip:port/` and jump to `http://ip:port/lecture/entropy_theory_basics` via webpage link. It can successfully load the navigation components. But when I type `http://ip:port/lecture/entropy_theory_basics` in the chrome directly, It still reported the error, `insertBefore` blabla.

Comment: No problem! I think you have a component or any other .vue file somewhere with the same problem as above. Make sure ALL components have a single root

Comment: But vue3 allows multiple nodes